# how to send a http request to get the response only when it changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I want to send a get HTTP request and get the response only when it changes. That is, is it possible to add something to the request so that it checks whether something has changed on the site or not, and only if something has changed, I received a response?

Comment: By site, do you mean the entire website or just the page the user is on?

Comment: Try reading about caching. https://medium.com/swlh/getting-started-with-caching-in-net-core-3079cab69efb

Comment: @Californium only page the user is on.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: @Californium nope

Comment: With React you are able to do this easily. Are you using plain JS and HTML? And what exactly are you referring to by “change”?

Comment: @Californium I'm only using node js to send a get request using fetch to a third party site.

Comment: @Alomen since you are not using a framework like React, you can maybe use the onChange event of the input elements on your page, so make the HTTP request on the onChange event of the elements.